# What is ARR_WORDS in a GHC heap profile?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The heap profile for my program, generated by `./program +RTS -hy -p`, is dominated by "ARR_WORDS". It doesn't correspond to anything obvious in my program; is it a GHC internal of some sort? How should I treat its dominating appearance in the profile?

I'm using GHC 7.0.3.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`ARR_WORDS` is the internal name of `ByteArray#`, which is a GHC type used to implement e.g. `ByteString`, `Text` and unboxed arrays.