# Why do hGetBuf, hPutBuf, etc. allocate memory?

Tags: haskell, io, profiling

In the process of doing some simple benchmarking, I came across something that surprised me. Take this snippet from [Network.Socket.Splice](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/splice-0.6.1.1/docs/src/Network-Socket-Splice-Internal.html#hSplice):

```hs
hSplice :: Int -> Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
hSplice len s t = do
  a <- mallocBytes len :: IO (Ptr Word8)
  finally
    (forever $! do
       bytes <- hGetBufSome s a len
       if bytes > 0
         then hPutBuf t a bytes
         else throwRecv0)
    (free a)
```

One would expect that `hGetBufSome` and `hPutBuf` here would not need to allocate memory, as they write into and read from a pre-allocated buffer. The [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/splice-0.6.1.1/docs/Network-Socket-Splice.html) seem to back this intuition up... But alas:

```
                                        individual     inherited
COST CENTRE                            %time %alloc   %time %alloc      bytes

 hSplice                                 0.5    0.0    38.1   61.1       3792
  hPutBuf                                0.4    1.0    19.8   29.9   12800000
   hPutBuf'                              0.4    0.4    19.4   28.9    4800000
    wantWritableHandle                   0.1    0.1    19.0   28.5    1600000
     wantWritableHandle'                 0.0    0.0    18.9   28.4          0
      withHandle_'                       0.0    0.1    18.9   28.4    1600000
       withHandle'                       1.0    3.8    18.8   28.3   48800000
        do_operation                     1.1    3.4    17.8   24.5   44000000
         withHandle_'.\                  0.3    1.1    16.7   21.0   14400000
          checkWritableHandle            0.1    0.2    16.4   19.9    3200000
           hPutBuf'.\                    1.1    3.3    16.3   19.7   42400000
            flushWriteBuffer             0.7    1.4    12.1    6.2   17600000
             flushByteWriteBuffer       11.3    4.8    11.3    4.8   61600000
            bufWrite                     1.7    6.9     3.0    9.9   88000000
             copyToRawBuffer             0.1    0.2     1.2    2.8    3200000
              withRawBuffer              0.3    0.8     1.2    2.6   10400000
               copyToRawBuffer.\         0.9    1.7     0.9    1.7   22400000
             debugIO                     0.1    0.2     0.1    0.2    3200000
            debugIO                      0.1    0.2     0.1    0.2    3200016
  hGetBufSome                            0.0    0.0    17.7   31.2         80
   wantReadableHandle_                   0.0    0.0    17.7   31.2         32
    wantReadableHandle'                  0.0    0.0    17.7   31.2          0
     withHandle_'                        0.0    0.0    17.7   31.2         32
      withHandle'                        1.6    2.4    17.7   31.2   30400976
       do_operation                      0.4    2.4    16.1   28.8   30400880
        withHandle_'.\                   0.5    1.1    15.8   26.4   14400288
         checkReadableHandle             0.1    0.4    15.3   25.3    4800096
          hGetBufSome.\                  8.7   14.8    15.2   24.9  190153648
           bufReadNBNonEmpty             2.6    4.4     6.1    8.0   56800000
            bufReadNBNonEmpty.buf'       0.0    0.4     0.0    0.4    5600000
            bufReadNBNonEmpty.so_far'    0.2    0.1     0.2    0.1    1600000
            bufReadNBNonEmpty.remaining  0.2    0.1     0.2    0.1    1600000
            copyFromRawBuffer            0.1    0.2     2.9    2.8    3200000
             withRawBuffer               1.0    0.8     2.8    2.6   10400000
              copyFromRawBuffer.\        1.8    1.7     1.8    1.7   22400000
            bufReadNBNonEmpty.avail      0.2    0.1     0.2    0.1    1600000
           flushCharReadBuffer           0.3    2.1     0.3    2.1   26400528
```

[image: heap profile by module]
[image: heap profile by type]

I have to assume this is on purpose... but I have no idea what that purpose might be. Even worse: I'm just barely clever enough to get this profile, but not quite clever enough to figure out exactly what's being allocated.

Any help along those lines would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:** I've done some more profiling with two drastically simplified testcases. The first testcase directly uses the read/write ops from [System.Posix.Internals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/System-Posix-Internals.html):

```
echo :: Ptr Word8 -> IO ()
echo buf = forever $ do
  threadWaitRead $ Fd 0
  len <- c_read 0 buf 1
  c_write 1 buf (fromIntegral len)
  yield
```

As you'd hope, this allocates no memory on the heap each time through the loop. The second testcase uses the read/write ops from [GHC.IO.FD](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-IO-FD.html):

```
echo :: Ptr Word8 -> IO ()
echo buf = forever $ do
  len <- readRawBufferPtr "read" stdin buf 0 1
  writeRawBufferPtr "write" stdout buf 0 (fromIntegral len)
```

---

**UPDATE #2:** I was advised to file this as a bug in GHC Trac... I'm still not sure it actually *is* a bug (as opposed to intentional behavior, a known limitation, or whatever) but here it is: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9696

Comment: Aren't you allocating memory to create `bytes`?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I don't think so... When I profile with `+RTS -hy`, the dominating type on the heap is `ARR_WORDS`. The type of `bytes` should be `Int` (the number of bytes read).

Comment: @mergeconflict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241470/what-is-arr-words-in-a-ghc-heap-profile#7241686 states that ARR_WORDS corresponds to ByteArray#. I don't know why so much is being allocated, but the pretty plateau in the profile indicates that the program runs in constant space.

Comment: @cheecheeo Yup, that's correct. I don't have a space leak; rather it seems like one or more small buffers are being allocated and freed each time through the loop.

Comment: Have you profiled code that does other operations (perhaps a no-op) and verified that you get different behaviour?

Comment: Do you know how many times the loop executed in the run that produced the allocation profile you posted?

Comment: Can you post a runnable example somewhere? (using the simplified case)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ba3cfa118e1d05870d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the conclusion is: [it's a bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9696).

Comment: It's not really a bug, just a missed opportunity for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to guess based on the [code](https://phabricator.haskell.org/diffusion/GHC/browse/master/libraries/base/GHC/IO/Handle/Text.hs;4b69d96b3d2758bbc06c58ea44a975c6e08d7400$868)

Runtime tries to optimize small reads and writes, so it maintains internal buffer. If your buffer is 1 byte long, it will be inefficient to use it dirrectly. So internal buffer is used to read bigger chunk of data. It is probably ~32Kb long. Plus something similar for writing. Plus your own buffer.

The code has an optimization -- if you provide buffer bigger then the internal one, and the later is empty, it will use your buffer dirrectly. But the internal buffer is already allocated, so it will not less memory usage. I don't know how to dissable internal buffer, but you can open feature request if it is important for you.

(I realize that my guess can be totally wrong.)

**ADD:**

> This one does seem to allocate, but I still don't know why.

What is your concern, max memory usage or number of allocated bytes?

`c_read` is a C function, it doesn't allocate on haskell's heap (but may allocate on C heap.)

`readRawBufferPtr` is Haskell function, and it is usual for haskell functions to allocate a lot of memory, that quickly becomes a garbage. Simply because of immutability. It is common for haskell program to allocate e.g 100Gb while memory usage is under 1Mb.

Comment: My concern is the CPU cost of allocation and GC, not max memory usage. For example: digging into the implementation of `readRawBufferPtr`, it seems like there's heap allocation happening in the call to `throwErrnoIfMinus1RetryMayBlock`; if I'm using this in a tight inner loop, I want this call spending as few cycles as possible. I don't think this is an example of allocation due to immutability / pure functional style.

Comment: @mergeconflict: It looks like the allocation is due to the use of higher-order functions (`throwErrnoIfMinus1RetryMayBlock`, as you mention) which are not getting optimized away. However, if you are concerned about the CPU cost of allocation, then you should be concerned about the CPU cost of everything GHC outputs, and not focus on allocation simply because it is easy to measure. An allocation is two instructions: increment a pointer and test it against the heap limit. Lots of GHC's output is worse than that, and it should all be negligible in comparison to doing the system call (`read`).

Comment: @mergeconflict So the concern is performance? You probably should reflect that in the question body and title. And why do you think memory allocation has anything to do with performance in your case? It may be the bottleneck, but that requires arguments.